# Upgrade failed and stuck due to corrupted libc install

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, glibc

I tried upgrading a server from Ubuntu 14 to 16 using the standard do-release-upgrade script. It all seemed to go well, until mid-way through, it showed me an error from libc, saying my 3.2 kernel wasn't supported, but it would try to upgrade anyways. I'm not sure why my server's using a 3.2 kernel, and why that wasn't also upgraded, but I selected "ok", the only option. It then tried to upgrade libc, but after 3 hours, it's seemingly stuck on the step "Checkinng init scripts..."

So I killed the upgrade, and ran into the normal broken package issues. Running `dpkg --configure -a` shows the problem is with libc, of course. However, if I try reinstalling libc, it just gets stuck at the same step. I tried upgrading my kernel, but that fails because it requires an up-to-date libc package.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. How do I fix libc from getting stuck at "Checking init scripts"?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 3.2? Was it upgraded from a previous release?

Comment: [This question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247836) on Ubuntu launchpad seems unusually similar. Based on what I've read, the first step is to try `sudo apt-get install -f` and see if it crashes, forcing you to cold reboot. If that's the case, you would, of course, have reason to suspect that your issue is the same. You might try out some of the other tests they did, and you might be able to use the same workaround. Of course, it could be a totally different issue...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I somehow accidentally set the server to use a very old kernel, even though more recent ones were installed. The solution was to reboot, and at the Grub boot screen, ensure the most recent kernel was selected, which for me was 3.13.

That allowed me to complete the upgrade by fixing the install of libc6 and running all other upgrades, including the installation of the standard Xenial kernel package, which got me to a 4.4 kernel.